# Put Validation on Filename using batch script

Tags: validation, batch-file, batch-processing, batch-rename

I have a bat file eg. TEST.bat which will have a period attached.
Example **TEST.bat_Mar-15_Mar** 
I want to put the validation as If first month i.e. Mar = second month in the file i.e. Mar, run the TEST.bat file else generate message - Invalid Filename.
The month should match in correct case as well.
File like TEST.bat_Mar-15_Apr or TEST.bat_Mar-15_mar will be treated as Invalid Filename.
I believe we need to call TEST.bat in this validation script.

Regards
Audi

Comment: I read your question multiple times and I do not understand at all what you want to achieve. Could you explain a bit more what you try to achieve ?

Comment: Also, if you're asking us to start and complete your project for you, Stack Overflow is not a coding service.  Please clearly explain the problem, and what you have attempted to try to solve it.

Comment: I Have a filename - Test_Apr_15_Apr.txt.
I want to put validation that if my first month i.e. Apr(filename:~5,3) = second month i.e. Apr (Filename:~12,3) then return condition true or else return False. There is an issue in the script which I am not been able to trace.
Please help

@ECHO OFF

cd C:\EPM_Batches\FDMEE_Batch\01TrialBalance\Script

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 FOR %%X IN (Test_*.txt) DO (
   set Filename=%%X
   set month1=!Filename:~5,3!
   set month2=!Filename:~11,3!
   echo !month1!
   echo !month2!
   )
 IF  EXIST !month1!==!month2!
 Echo True
 ELSE 
 Echo False
 
PAUSE

Comment: @ECHO OFF

cd C:\EPM_Batches\FDMEE_Batch\01TrialBalance\Script

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
 FOR %%X IN (Test_*.txt) DO (
   set Filename=%%X
   set month1=!Filename:~5,3!
   set month2=!Filename:~11,3!
   echo !month1!
   echo !month2!
   )
 IF  EXIST !month1!==!month2!
 Echo True
 ELSE 
 Echo False
 
PAUSE

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in

```
IF EXIST !month1!==!month2! Echo True ELSE Echo False
```

Firstly, you mustn't write EXIST because you compare month1 and month2. EXIST is used to check whether a file exist. These situations are different.
Secondly, you must use () for if block like (echo true).
Finally, your code must be like:

```
IF !month1!==!month2! (Echo True) ELSE Echo False
```

And i advise you to see the help explanation of if. Because my answer exists in there.